# Name of a part inside 2012 MBP 15", below RAM slots, little pins to keep bottom cover from hitting electronics

Tags: macbook-pro, repair

I am trying to figure out the name of a tiny black doohicky part inside my 2012 15" Macbook Pro (unibody, non-retina). It's right below the RAM slots, between the RAM and the battery when you open up the laptop. I have circled the part in this picture from the iFixit teardown of said laptop.

[image: relevant part in red]

There are two springy pins coming out of the part. I think it is intended to keep the bottom cover from hitting the electronics when it is closed. In my laptop one of the pins is not springy anymore, so I want to try and replace it. I have no idea what the part would be called or what search term I would use though. I was hoping someone might have an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would call it (bar)-spacer and the part number seems to be 6813-1946 (or 6818-1946). Usually apple part numbers have the form 000-0000.

I searched for the part at [powerbookmedic](http://www.powerbookmedic.com/) but it's not available there.